# How to limit my website to 1 tab (Next.JS)

Tags: typescript, web, next.js, game-development

So I'm a frontend/game developer, so I've decided to make a game.. **on a website**.

So I've wanted to limit the game to 1 tab as in 2 tabs it would cause some duplication bugs.
I've tried searching for this topic but all I found we're questions from 5 years ago and stuff that don't work with Next.JS. May anyone help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you have the game setup where it requires the user to login. In your database, you can specify an "inGame" field and block the user from starting any new sessions when they try to login.

There is no good way to do this locally, as users could easily get around cookies and local storage by opening a private browser.

Comment: Hey @EJZ, thank you for responding. The game already has a database setup, are you saying to add a field named inGame, which is set to true whenever the user visits the website? if so how would it be turned into false when the user leaves?

Comment: Yes I am proposing that. You can "ping" the server every one second, for example with the last played time. If that time is greater than say 10 seconds, the session will automatically close and set inGame to false. If you don't want to write cloud functions such as that, you could just ping the time and locally from the website it can do the math if the user is currently in a game (if it pinged one second ago they are, if it pinged 15 hours ago they are not).